# Error while uploading videos to youtube channel

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to upload videos to youtube channel via youtube API. I have created a channel in youtube, created developer key. But it's not uploading the videos. Kindly assist me.

Here is the exception:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

Here is the code:

```
 try
            {
                YouTubeRequestSettings setting;
                YouTubeRequest request;
                string DevKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

                setting = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Channel Name", DevKey);

                request = new YouTubeRequest(setting);
                Video newVideo = new Video();
                newVideo.Title = Title;
                newVideo.Description = Description;
                newVideo.Private = true;

                newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(filestream, "filename", "videp/mp4");
                Video CreateVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
                return CreateVideo.VideoId;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which API you are using. It looks like you are using YouTube Data API v2 in a C# application. v2 is depricated and you should use v3! You can install it in your application using the NuGet package manager. Then you can simply upload a video following this example: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

Please note that an authentication using the correct scope is needed to upload videos to a youtube channel. I can not find the authentication in your code sample. The devkey alone is not enough. You need to create an OAuth authentication using the correct credentials (client ID, client secret and redirect URI). You can download the credentials as a JSON-file from your developer console and use it in your application as shown in the example I linked above.

Hope this helps

garv3